# I can't get my Jquery to work: Need to add img tag dynamically upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the below code, I am trying to get an img tag to load somewhere on the page when you click on a button. This is just for testing purposes, but I need to get it to work. The img tag is a 1 by 1 pixel that is supposed to track that something was clicked on. I know that an a tag would be better suited for this purpose, but for reasons I can't explain here, this cannot be used.

Any advice you can give to get the below code working would be great. I will test in Fiddler to confirm.

If you need more information or clarification, please let me know.

I appreciate your help!

Thanks,

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">

#button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:orange;
    font-family:cursive, arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: brown;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
}

#output {
    font-family:garamond;
    color:black;
    height:450px;
    width:320px;
    border-radius:2px;
    border-color:black;
    background-color:white;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#button').click(function(){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML +=('<img height="1" width="1" src="http://view.atdmt.com/action/AAA_ImageTest"/>');
 });
});

</script>

<body>

<div id="button">Test</div>
<div id="output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, then use it: `$("#output").html('<img height="1" width="1" src="http://view.atdmt.com/action/AAA_ImageTest"/>');`

Comment: @Kamui I've updated my answer to bypass the browser cache when requesting same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#button').click(function(){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML +=('<img height="1" width="1" src="http://view.atdmt.com/action/AAA_ImageTest"/>');
 });
});
```

With this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#output').append('<img height="1" width="1" src="http://view.atdmt.com/action/AAA_ImageTest"/>');
    });
});
```

Using `.append("<img..)` will add another `img` every time you click. If this is not what you're expecting then edit your question with more details about how you want it to work.

Comment: This won't add another if you click again.

Comment: I've updated so that it will. Also what's the point of adding another identical image?

Comment: What's the point of adding a 1x1 image in the first place? It's not our place to judge that.

Comment: It's supposed to track each time a button is clicked. When the domain is called, our server will track that this pixel loaded and therefore that the button was clicked. We have an easier way to do this, but a specific scenario came up and I'm currently testing to see our options.

Comment: For some reason, I don't see the call come up in Fiddler, which is our web trafficking program that we use. I feel like it's being added correctly at this point, but I guess it might only work upon page load. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Well this does answer your question but doesn't solve your problem. Maybe if you ask about detecting clicks on the server you might find a better solution to your issue.

Comment: My guess would be the image is cached on the browser, so a second request is never made to the server. Look at the HTTP headers of the first request/response, and look for Cache-Control, ETag, Last-Modified-Date, and other related headers, to see if that's the case. You should be able to adjust your image's response headers if you find that they're getting cached.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#output').prepend('<img height="1" width="1" src="http://view.atdmt.com/action/AAA_ImageTest"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').on('click',function(e) { //.on() preferred, click() is a short-hand for this
        e.preventDefault(); //if you change from div to `A` someday

        var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

        //creating IMG on-the-fly, adding css and appending it
        $('<img />', {
            'src': 'http://view.atdmt.com/action/AAA_ImageTest?ts='+timestamp
        }).css({
            'width':'1px',
            'height':'1px', 
            'border':0
        }).appendTo('#output');     
    });
});
```

Instead of making the HTML on had and adding as HTML, I'm creating the `img` on-the-fly, adding it's CSS and appending to `#output`.

`e.preventDefault` it's just for blocking default behavior of an item. That's just a bonus if someday you change from `<div id="button">Test</div>` to an actual anchor `<a id="button" href="#">Test</a>`.

Update:
@Kamui To prevent image caching (thus not making a second call when adding another one), I've added a timestamp on the image URL.

Comment: One thing to watch out for - on `img` tags, the `height` and `width` attributes are different from the CSS `height` and `width` properties. I forget all the details, but it's something to do with the container size before image is loaded.

Comment: @JoeEnos The attributes `width` and `height` are the exact equivalent of those in CSS. There's no need for them (by creating more code using `attr()` for e.g) if you can declare all of them in `css()`. The only difference is that the attributes only accept number and the number will be converted to `pixel` while on CSS you can use any.

Comment: I read in a few places that there was some difference related to pending/failed images. But I can't reproduce that now - CSS seems to behave the same as the inline attributes. All I'm finding now are people describing differences in ideology (presentation vs. functionality vs. design etc.). Looks like CSS always wins if they're both defined. It is noteworthy though that they did not deprecate `height` and `width` in HTML5, so that tells me someone thinks it's still meaningful.

Comment: @JoeEnos Yeah, I've read the w3c docs and really isn't deprecated on HTML5 but couldn't find a 'why'. And yes, inline CSS always wins against attributes. If you check with Chrome Dev Tools, you'll see that they are overwritten with the css counterparts.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to append the pure-jQuery way:

```
jQuery("#output").append(
    jQuery("<img>")
        .attr("height", "1")
        .attr("width", "1")
        .attr("src", "http://view.atdmt.com/action/AAA_ImageTest")
);
```

This will create an `img` object in the jQuery world, then append it to your output div. This method (as opposed to writing one big long string) is nice because it keeps everything clean - no worrying about escaping quotes, and it would be very easy to add dynamic values in there for some of the attributes.

Comment: `<img></img>` does not exist. `img` is a self-closed element.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL You're right - I've always seen it written that way even for tags like `image` or `input`. jQuery is forgiving and does properly insert the tag into the DOM either way, but I really should have written it properly.